# Html, CSS code not running in some mobile devices Chrome app?

Tags: html, css

The frontend HTML and CSS code are not working in various mobile devices Chrome App. If we check in the chrome Inspect tool in desktop then the bottom navigation menu is displayed but in my Nokia mobile, the bottom nav bar is not displayed.
**Q. How to resolve this issue?**

[Picture when Navbar is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77RN6.jpg)
[Picture when the navigation bar is not displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWylb.jpg)

The Website link is - [**Free Job Alert**](https://www.highonstudy.com/free-job-alert/)

Code -

```css
@media (min-width: 500px)  { .btmenu {display:none;} } 

.mbn { position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; z-index:99999999; will-change: transform; transform: translateZ(0); display: flex; height: 50px; box-shadow: 0 -3px 15px -3px #999; background-color: #fdfdfd; } .mbn a { color:#000000; text-decoration:none; border-right:1px solid #dddddd;} .mbn-item { flex-grow: 1; text-align: center; font-size: 12px; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; } .mbn-content { display: flex; color:#ffffff; flex-direction: column; }
```

```html
<div class="btmenu">
<div class="mbn"> <div class="mbn-item"> <div class="mbn-content"> <a href="https://www.highonstudy.com/category/new-govt-job/"> <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i><br>Jobs</a> </div> </div> <div class="mbn-item"> <div class="mbn-content"> <a href="https://www.highonstudy.com/category/current-affairs-today/"> <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i><br>C. Affairs</a> </div> </div> <div class="mbn-item"> <div class="mbn-content"> <a href="#blog_subscription-12"> <i class="fa fa-group"></i><br>Subscribe</a> </div> </div> <div class="mbn-item"> <div class="mbn-content"> <a href="https://www.highonstudy.com/e-store/"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><br>Shop</a> </div> </div> <div class="mbn-item"> <div class="mbn-content"> <a onclick="hi_open()"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> <br>Menu</a> </div> </div> </div> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could remove the media query and check again. If it then does work then maybe the resolution of your mobile device is different then the one you are expecting

Comment: I suggest you improve the title of your question. It is too generic and doesn't describe the specific problem. It will help people engage faster and help you

Comment: @Jelle, I have tried out as you mention but not working.

Comment: What exactly is not working? On the website I see the bottom bar appear if I remove the min-width part. So that means the bottom bar css is working properly. 

Just play around with the min-width value until it appears on your specific mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example of where the bottom bar doesn't appear seems to have a width of 725px.

So if you would change the values then it should appear

Try out:

```
@media (min-width: 750px)  { .btmenu {display:none;} }
```

Maybe that is not the exact value, but best to just play around with the value since the rest seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your bar only shows for screens below 400px of width. Your devices have different width - one below 400px, second above 400px.

Here's your code which is doing this.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px)
.btmenu {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I want to show this navbar only in mobile, so what should be the exact css?

Comment: @PuneetVerma CSS does not support detecting what device is being used. It allows only to detect width. Usually people set below 768px as mobile views, 768px to 1024px as tablets, 1024px to 1280px as laptops/desktops and >1280px as large screens. But those are just some arbitrary numbers and not guarantee. Try to set layout based on how much information you need/can put on screen, no what kind of device is user using.

Answer (score -1):

This is working on scroll ( on mobile devices ) check

Comment: Scrolling function is working properly but bottom menu is not display in chrome. I have a Nokia device and Asus device, in Nokia the bottom nav bar is not display but in Asus it's display. See both images above.